# Is there a way to check NodeJs schedule's last job execution status?

Tags: node.js, schedule

I'm using this module https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule to schedule a job which runs every 3 minutes. However, there might be a certain occasion, where this Job execution might take more than 3 minutes. I observe that multiple instances of job start running if the previous job is not successfully completed yet.

Is there a way to verify the status of last execution? So as to avoid any future job execution, until last execution is over?

```
var ruleResetLimits = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
ruleResetLimits.minute = new schedule.Range(0, 59, 3)


schedule.scheduleJob(ruleResetLimits, function () {

    async.waterfall([
            async.apply(getPreviousBuildInformation, envs, envMap, DATA_PATH),
            getActiveEndpointsAndVersion,
            compareBuildInformation,
            sendMessages,
            saveCurrentBuildInfo
        ],
        function (err, results, logger) {
            callBackForScript(err, results, logger)
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: _I observe that multiple instances of job start running_ Can you provide a [mcve]? It's difficult to give good feedback without it, as it's currently very easy to provide a solution that may not apply to you.

Comment: There is no need to provide the code as it is not code specific issue. What I want to know is, if there is a way to check in "node-schedule" for the last/previous execution? 
I've updated the question for your reference.

Comment: The answer to that is no. If your code is asynchronous, which is must be if you say concurrent executions are possible, then `node-schedule` has no way of knowing when the asynchronous control flow is complete. If your code was synchronous, then it would block the event loop until it was done, which would make it impossible for `node-schedule` to run the next job until the event loop was unblocked. _However_ if you provided specific code, there are ways to keep track of the progress of asynchronous control flow yourself. Now that you have specific code this can be answered.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. So that I don't waste my time in writing custom code and testing it if there is a way already in node-schedule. Thanks Patrick.